# Why does the pop-up calendar not click into the next month (python, selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a simple code below to open the reservation calendar and click to the following month, but the calendar doesn't seem to be switching to the next month.  Is there something glaring that I am missing?

```
driver.get("https://www.tablecheck.com/shops/peterluger/reserve")
driver.maximize_window() 

driver.find_element_by_id("reservation_start_date").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Next Month']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before click the element, try to move first to the target.

Learn about [**`ActionChains`**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#action-chains):

```
driver.get("https://www.tablecheck.com/shops/peterluger/reserve")
driver.maximize_window() 

driver.find_element_by_id("reservation_start_date").click()

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Next Month']")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: Why ? There is no need to click on calendar itself. Why to have much complexity and failure chances by having one more locator `//div[@aria-label='Next Month']` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Your answer fills directly the target date, and it's good and simple execution. But this answer tries to provide another solution to the OP about *`Why does the pop-up calendar not click....`* since the `.click()` method doesn't work.

Comment: @frianH thank you! worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The outer HTML

```
<input class="form-control mobidate i-txt refresh-menu-items mbsc-comp" readonly="" placeholder="-- Select Date --" type="text" name="reservation[start_date]" id="reservation_start_date" value="2021-10-13">
```

shows that it has an value attribute in form of `2021-10-13`.

We **do not need to click** on this `input field` and then `select a value from the calendar`.

Instead we can directly `pass the value attribute` using `execute script` in **Python-Selenium bindings**.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.tablecheck.com/shops/peterluger/reserve")
date = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "reservation_start_date")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", date)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '2021-10-13')", date)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thank you so much!  though this wasn't the exact problem I was solving for, it was something else i had been struggling with so much appreciated.  And yes, this way is much simpler.

Comment: when I apply this code, the field gets populated with the specified date, but it doesn't seem like the value is recognized on the page (i.e. the field still remains red instead of grey).  Is an additional line of code required to 'activate' the value that's set?

Comment: If You can do something without interaction with UI elements in automation. You should always opt for that. You really do not need to click on the date picker, simply use javascript to pass the value.